# Pagination in Microsoft Graph APi to get users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using graph api to get users of an organization. To implement pagination i used $top parameter which also gave me @odata.nextLink to get next page. No I want previous page when user click on Previous button. I tried using $skip, $previous-page=true parameters but did not work.
Links I have used are

- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=10
- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$skip=10 (tried to redirect to the 2nd page from 4th page but this doesn't work)
- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$previous-page=true&$top=10 (Only gave 1st 10 users and next link)

Please help me to redirect to previous page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't supported, nor is it what paging was intended for. Pagination is a performance optimization that works by reducing the amount of data transmitted with each call to the API. It is not designed to directly back a UI.

Your app should be pulling down the data as needed and caching it. When the user moves forward, you fetch data from the API. When the user moves backward, you fetch data from your cache.

Comment: I faced same issue as OP.. In the case of driveItems, if we cache data returned from the api in order to move between pages, another user could upload a new file in the prev page, and we wouldn't see it with this cache system. Is the only solution here using a webhook to invalidate the cache and restart process of fetching from zero/skipping tokens until we land on same page ?